# How do I find whether I got the right AC?

Tags: electrical, air-conditioning

Recently i bought AC (LG

> LS-Q18HNZA

) 2020 series. Somehow i feel i got cheated due to the below reasons.

- There is no printing "New 2020 series" on the indoor unit box.
- There is not stickers related to 2020 series on the indoor unit.
- The remote does not contain 4-in-1 button.

How do i check whether i got the 2020 series product.

Answer (score 1):

The labeling on the box and the unit not having "2020 series" doesn't mean a thing, that an advertising thing. The remote being different could be a clue. Run it by your installer. Also, get the serial numbers, not the model numbers, off of the units and get with customer service and have them check the records. Verify the warranty cards.